# linq query and use result to set property

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects and i need to set a field based on whether or not a field holds a unique value.

Consider a ticket class with two properties

```
public class Ticket
{
    public string TicketNumber { get; set; }

    public bool IsUnique { get; set; }
}
```

I receive a list of tickets and pass these to a function:

```
 IList<Ticket>
```

Using linq I would like to iterate over this list and if a given ticket number is unique in that list, set the bool IsUnique to true.

I have the following so far

```
public void UpdateTickets(IList<Ticket> Tickets)
    {
        foreach (var ticket in tickets)
        {
            // if ticketNumber occurs once
            // set isUnique to true, otherwise false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Consider creating a new string list with your unique tickets with Distinct method.
 `List<string> NewList = Tickets.Select(x=>x.TicketNumber).Distinct().ToList();` Edit: Oh sorry, I misunderstood the question. You want to mark unique tickets without touching repeating ones.

Comment: do you want to discard the duplicates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
foreach (var g in tickets.GroupBy(x => x.TicketNumber))
{
    var unique = !g.Skip(1).Any();
    foreach (var ticket in g)
    {
        ticket.IsUnique = unique;
    }
}
```

We group tickets with the same number together and than we check of there are more than 1 item in the group.

Answer (score 3):

**Since I've neglected the code comment `// set isUnique to true, otherwise false` Magnus answer is to be preferred.**

1. Group by ticket number / id
2. Filter out those groups with multiple items
3. Flatten the results back
4. The resulting collection is those items, which are unique by its number

```
public void UpdateTickets(IList<Ticket> tickets)
{
    var uniqueTickets = tickets.GroupBy (t => t.TicketNumber)
        .Where (t => t.Count () == 1)
        .SelectMany (t => t);

    foreach (var ticket in uniqueTickets)
    {
        ticket.IsUnique = true;
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EgICJr

Comment: this will take out only those tickets that are unique, don't we want to maintain all the items?

Comment: We are only manipulating the items in the list. We are not removing any items from that list

Comment: How about this, improved >  `var uniqueTickets = tickets.GroupBy(t => t.TicketNumber).Where(t => t.Count() == 1).SelectMany(t => t).Select(x => new Ticket {Number = x.TicketNumber, IsUnique = true}).ToList();`

Comment: certainly possible, altough this list is now stored in that variable, but the original list is not changed. You'd have to return that `uniqueTickets` to the caller.

Comment: obviously, but we shouldn't be just modifying a list in a void method and return nothing

Comment: @Aarif If the method is called `UpdateTickets` than I would expect it to do just that.

Comment: I guess this comes down to coding guidelines, standards and personal preference. My goal was to solve the OPs problem in a relative readable and performant way, as close to his code as possible,

Comment: yeah it is, but won't it be better if it reads the info returns the updated list ?

Comment: What is missing in the answer is setting `IsUnique` to false (if it is not unique) since we don't know the previous value.

Comment: @Magnus correct. OP only wanted to set unique to true, if it was unique. That is the way I read his question.

Comment: @Marco He actually says: `set isUnique to true, otherwise false`

Comment: bloody hell - I completly overlooked the comment,

Comment: @Magnus I could now shamelessly update my answer, but in the end that would just copy yours, regardless if I use `.Count() ==1 ` or `.Skip(1).Any()`, so I'll just dont and refer to your answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
tickets.GroupBy(t => t.TicketNumber)
    .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
    .ForEach(g => g.ForEach(t => t.IsUnique = true));
```

I'd need this extension method to enable the `.ForEach()` syntax though:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (var item in enumerable)
    {
        action(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in single Linq.

```
Tickets.GroupBy(grptckt => grptckt.TicketNumber)
       .Where(tckt => tckt.Count() == 1)
       .Select(val => val.FirstOrDefault().IsUnique = true)
       .ToList();
```

GroupBy: Grouping tickets with ticket number.
Where: Check Ticket Number is not repeating with checking count in grouping.
Select: Select unique Ticket and update isUnique to true.
ToList: Update Existing list with changes into same list.